# How to get the 15/15 badges achievement for A.V.A?

Tags: steam, achievements, alliance-of-valiant-arms

Alliance of Valiant Arms (A.V.A) has these end of the match badge rewards which give you more of a reward for contributing to the mission.
However in all of my time playing I only seem to have unlocked 10 out of the 15 required badges to get the steam achievement.

The strangest thing is: I main pointsman (5+k kills), but don't have any badge for that class while I got the Assault rifle marksman badge (for rifleman with only 120 kills played)

The badges I'm talking about: http://ava.aeriagames.com/guide/badges
The information given is very vague, and should have given me countless badges for pointsman if it only meant being good as they say.

**I would like to know the requirement for each of these badges**
There are some very obvious ones but having a nice list for everyone would be nice.